# Individuals reproduce and mutate

Tags: beginner, performance, simulation, julia

**How can I improve the performance (in terms of computation time) of this code?**

```
# Settings
const nbloci = 100         # length of the genome
const N = 100              # Number individuals in the population
const nbgenerations = 100  # number of generations
const mu = 1/10^5          # mutation rate
const s = 0.01             # effect of a given mutation on fitness

# Packages
using Distributions.Binomial
using Distributions.wsample

# Type and Functions
type Ind
    Genome
end

function makepopulation(N)
    Pop = Array(Ind, N)
    for i = 1:N
        Pop[i] = Ind(ones(Float64, nbloci))
    end
    return(Pop)
end

function calculatefitnesses(Pop)
    fitnesses = Array(Float64, N)
    for (i,I) = enumerate(Pop)
        fit = 1
        for l = I.Genome
            fit *= l
        end
        fitnesses[i] = fit
    end
    return(fitnesses)
end

function mutate(I)
    nbmut = rand(Binomial(nbloci, mu), 1)[1]
    mutposs = rand(1:nbloci, nbmut)
    for mutpos = mutposs
        I.Genome[mutpos] == 1.0 ? I.Genome[mutpos] = mutfit : I.Genome[mutpos] = 1.0
    end
end

function reproduce(Pop)
    fitnesses = calculatefitnesses(Pop)
    newPop = Array(Ind, N)
    for i = 1:N
        newPop[i] = deepcopy(wsample(Pop, fitnesses, 1)[1])
        mutate(newPop[i])
    end
    return(newPop)
end

##### MAIN #####

# Just a useful constant
const mutfit = 1.0-s

# Simulation
Pop = makepopulation(N)             # Create population
for generation = 1:nbgenerations    # Iterate over all generations
    Pop = reproduce(Pop)           
end
```

The above code simulates a population of individuals (`Ind`) that all have a genome long of `nbloci` (independent) loci (a locus (=sing. of loci) is a position on a chromosome). `makepopulation` creates a population of clones at the beginning of the simulation. Then, iterating over all generations (`for` loop) the function `reproduce` is called on the population. The function `reproduce` calls `calcfitnesses` who return an array of fitnesses. `reproduce` sample the individuals according to `fitnesses` and then mutate the sampled individuals by calling the function `mutate`. After reproducing, all individuals die (no overlap of generations).

In `mutate`, each locus has a probability `mu` of mutating. In `calcfitness` an individual that has for example 8 mutant alleles (allele=variant of a gene) has a fitness of `(1-s)^8`. In `reproduce`, individuals are chosen to reproduce with some probability given by their fitness. `N` designates the population size and `nbgenerations` obviously designates the number of generations to simulate.

**My main doubts and questions**

- The `calcfitness` function might eventually be improved by first counting the number of mutants and then using a power function to calculate the `fit` of an `Ind`. In such case, I may eventually want to code `True/False` instead of the `Float64` objects `1.0/1.0-s` in their genome. I could as well have an Array where at position `i` is the fitness of on individual that has `i` mutations. What do you think would be the best solution?
- I feel like I used lots of functions and an eventually unnecessary type. It has the advantage to make the code easier to read, but does it significantly slow down the simulations?
- I am not 100% sure about the use of the `const` prefix in my settings either. Would I be better off passing all these settings to each function instead of defining them as constant?
- There might have a better solution than deep-copying all individuals forming the next generation. Would it be better to sample them all first and then to deep-copy only the individuals that has been sampled more than once?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving very short names and commneting next to them the meaning

```
const nbloci = 100         # length of the genome
const N = 100              # Number individuals in the population
const nbgenerations = 100  # number of generations
const mu = 1/10^5          # mutation rate
const s = 0.01             # effect of a given mutation on fitness
```

It would be better to give long and self-explanatory names without comments:

```
const genome_length = 100
const population_size = 100 
const no_generations = 100
const mutation_rate = 1/10^5
const s = 0.01                # effect of a given mutation on fitness # Too criptic for  me to understand
```

---

Many beginners think:

> If I write many many many comments everywhere in my code, it will for sure become better!

But this is not True, you should remove all the meaningless comments such as:

- `# Settings`
- `# Packages`
- `# Type and Functions`

---

> Maybe using functions will slow down my code very much?

No, the opposite, [code inside functions runs much faster](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/).

But you should

> Avoid writing overly-specific types

(Reference is again the link above).

---

```
for l = I.Genome
```

Readibility counts, avoid using names like `l` and `I` because it is easy to mistake one for the other.

```
mutpos = mutposs
```

same as above.

---

> Is there a way to improve the calcfitness step, maybe by coding
>   true/false instead of 1/1-s?

No, fitness must be a number, if you use a true/false value for the fitness then you are not searching genetically but randomly.

Comment: Interesting points about the naming convention. I will sure  follow those guidelines in the future. Good to know about the use of functions as well. +1. Is there a way to improve the `deepcopying` step? Is there a way to improve the `calcfitness` step, maybe by coding `true/false` instead of `1/1-s`?